# Find the basis of the Ker(T) and Im(T) for $T: P_3 \to P_3$, $T(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)=dx^3+cx^2+bx+a$

Tags: linear-algebra

For the linear application, $T: P_3 \to P_3$, $T(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)=dx^3+cx^2+bx+a$, find

1. A matrix representation with respect to a basis of your choice
2. A basis of Ker(T)
3. A basis of Im(T)

What I have done so far...

**Matrix representation:** Taking a closer look at the map and the matrix operations, we can easily see that the matrix representation will be $\ldots$

**Corrected Matrix:**
$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & d \\ 0 & 0 & c & 0 \\ 0 & b & 0 & 0 \\ a & 0 & 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix}  $

Because

$\begin{pmatrix} d & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & c & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & b & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & a  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x^3 \\ x^2 \\ x \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} =T(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)$

**Basis of Ker(T):** You have to find the set of all $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d \in P_3$ such that $$T(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)=(0,0,0,0)^T$$

We consider

$\begin{pmatrix} d & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & c & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & b & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & a  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x^3 \\ x^2 \\ x \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Which will result in the following equations:
\begin{cases} 
      dx^3=0 \\
      cx^2=0 \\
      bx=0 \\
      a=0 \\
      \end{cases}

**Is this correct?** I do not know how to proceed. I know we have to find $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ in $P_3$ such that T(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)=0.

**Basis of Im(T):** If we just want to have a set of vectors which span the image, then it would be enough to take the column-vectors. But we want to have linear-independent vectors, which span our image.

What we have to do now: Consider $T^{T}$ matrix of T and apply the Gaussian-elimination-algorithm on it. The columns which you will obtain then form a basis of the image.

**Need help**

So the basis of the Im(T) is the vector columns of the matrix.

Comment: your matrix representation is not quite correct. The coefficients $a,b,c,d$ change with each polynomial. You are on the right track. The matrix should be sort of the flip of the identity matrix.

Comment: Hence is my matrix correct now?

Comment: Not quite, your matrix shouldn't have $a,b,c,d$ in it. These are arbitrary and vary with each element of the vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way: choose basis $\displaystyle \{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ of $P_3$. Then check:

$$T[x^3]=1$$

$$T[x^2]=x$$

$$T[x]=x^2$$

$$T[1]=x^3$$

So first element of basis is transofmed to fourth  by $T$, second to third, third to second, fourth to first. So the matrix representation is:

$$T=\begin{bmatrix}0 && 0 && 0 && 1 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 1 && 0 && 0 && 0\end{bmatrix}$$.

Now you can check that $\det T \neq 0$, so Ker(T)=$\{0\}$, so basis of Ker(T) is $\{0\}$, Im(T)=$P_3$, so basis Im(T) is $P_3$, for example, $\displaystyle \{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$.

Comment: How is the Ker(T) empty if you just stated that $Ker(T)=\{0\}$?

Comment: The Kernel of a linear map is never empty since $0$ is always in it. But because $det T\not=0$ the map is injective and so $0$ is the only element of the kernel.

Comment: Ok, I corrected the mistake.